# unable to start program, unrecognized error in windows web services framework

Tags: c#, c++

My c# console app calls a managed c++ dll. The dll is added as a reference to the c# project. If I try to start in debug mode it says error while trying to run project. unable to start program, unrecognized error in windows web service framework. It is not a web application. If I run without debugging, the console pops up and my dll produces an error that the hdf5 header files don't match the hdf5 library my c++ dll is linked to (though it compiles and builds just fine). Both c# driver and c++ dll are 64 bit on a 64 bit machine.
Both the F5 and ctrl F5 errors are puzzling. Hope someone has info on this.
thanks,
sb

Comment: You need to actually ask a question.

Comment: Question is -- how do I resolve the two errors I am getting?

Comment: it was a mcAfee firewall issue. we had to add an exception for ipv6

Answer (score 22):

Try to change your target CPU. Go to Properties of your project->Build-Platform Target and set value to x86.

That worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

1. Clean solution old files using `Menu -> Build -> Clean Solution`
2. In your `project properties` select `compile tab` and enable the checkbox `Prefer 32bit` or change the `Target CPU` to `X86`
3. Try to compile/debug again after applying steps above

Comment: was getting the same error message as the OP, setting prefer 32 bit fixed it.  why?

Answer (score 1):

I too had to restart Visual Studio.  Rebuilding solution & cleaning solution made no difference; the solution had recently built & ran just fine.

Once I restarted Visual Studio and reran, there was no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just got this error, and restarting Visual Studio helped for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was being blocked by our firewall